# Openssl_Uplink no Openssl_Applink

Tags: delphi, openssl, delphi-xe2

In an application that calls a DLL, which implements the Electronic bill in Mexico, the error OPENSSL_UPLINK OPENSSL_APPLINK terminates the process(crash).

When you debug the DLL, I look that error is when I load the CER files. and .KEY

The following is my master code.

```
function TFacturacion.Validar_Certificado : boolean;
var
  Certificado : TCertificado;
begin
  Certificado := TCertificado.Create;
try
 begin
  Certificado.LoadFromFile(DmDatos.IBDs_SistemaCERTFNAME.AsString);
  case TipoCertificado(Certificado.Base64) of
tcDESCONOCIDO : begin
     FRespuestaCFD := 'Certificado Desconocido o de Pruebas';
     Result := False;
    end;
    tcFIEL : begin
     FRespuestaCFD := 'Certificado FIEL';
     Result := False;
    end;
    tcCSD : begin
     Result := True;
    end;
 end;         // Fin Case
end;          // Fin Begin protegido(TRY)
Except
 Result := False;
 FRespuestaCFD := 'Error en Certificado....No se pudo localizar el Archivo .CER';
end;

if Result = False then
 begin
  Certificado.Free;
  Certificado := NIl;
   Exit;
 end;

CertificadoB64 := Certificado.Base64;
Certificado.Free;
Certificado := Nil;

end;

function TFacturacion.Validar_Llave : Boolean;
var Llave : TLlavePrivada;
begin
 Result := False;
 Llave := TLlavePrivada.Create;

 if Llave.DER_LoadFromFile(DmDatos.IBDs_SistemaKEYFNAME.AsString,         DmDatos.IBDs_SistemaCLAVEPRIVADA.AsString ) then
 begin
  FLlaveB64 := Llave.Base64;
  Result := True;
 end
 else
  begin
    FRespuestaCFD := 'Error al abrir la Llave, es posible que la clave no sea la correcta';
 end;

Llave.Free;
Llave := Nil;

end;
```

The following is my code of the unit where the functions are coded

```
procedure TX509Certificate.LoadFromFile(FileName: string);
 begin
  LoadFromFile(Filename, auto);
 end;

procedure TX509Certificate.LoadFromFile(FileName: string; Encoding: TEncoding);
var
 certfile: pBIO;
 p12: pPKCS12;
 a: pEVP_PKEY;
 c: pX509;
 ca: pSTACK_OFX509;
begin
 c := nil;

 if not(Encoding in [auto, DER, PEM, NETSCAPE, PKCS12]) then
raise EOpenSSL.Create('Bad certificate encoding.');

 if not FileExists(FileName) then
raise EOpenSSL.Create('Certificate file not found ('+FileName+')');

 certfile := BIO_new(BIO_s_file());

 if certfile = nil then
raise EOpenSSL.Create('Error creating BIO.');

 BIO_read_filename(certfile, ToChar(FileName));

 if (Encoding = auto) or (encoding = DER) then
  begin
fCertificate := d2i_X509_bio(certfile, nil);
if (Encoding = auto) and (fCertificate = nil) then
  BIO_reset(certfile);
  end;

 if ((Encoding = auto) and (fCertificate = nil)) or (encoding = NETSCAPE) then
  begin
// See apps.c
  end;

 if ((Encoding = auto) and (fCertificate = nil)) or (encoding = PEM) then
  begin
fCertificate := PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX(certfile, c, nil, nil);
if (Encoding = auto) and (fCertificate = nil) then
 BIO_reset(certfile);
  end;

 if ((Encoding = auto) and (fCertificate = nil)) or (encoding = PKCS12) then  
  begin
p12 := d2i_PKCS12_bio(certfile, nil);
PKCS12_parse(p12, nil, a, c, ca);
fCertificate := c;
PKCS12_free(p12);
p12 := nil;
  end;

  BIO_free(certfile);
  if fCertificate = nil then
raise EOpenSSL.Create('Unable to read certificate from file ' + FileName + '.');
end;

function TPKCS8.DER_LoadFromFile(DERFname, PrivateKey: string) : boolean;
var
 bioDER : pBIO;
 p8 : pX509_SIG;
 p8inf : pPKCS8_Priv_Key_Info;
begin
 //OpenSSL pkcs8 -inform DER -in DERFName -passin pass:PrivateKey

 Result := false;

 bioDER := nil; p8 := nil;

 if FileExists(DERFname) then
  try
bioDER := BIO_new(BIO_s_file());
BIO_read_filename(bioDER,ToChar(DERFName));
p8 := d2i_PKCS8_bio(bioDER,nil);
if p8 = nil then exit; //El archivo no es un .key bien formado
//------HERE CRASH-----------------------------------------------
p8inf := PKCS8_decrypt(p8,ToChar(PrivateKey),length(PrivateKey));
//-------------------------------------------------------------
if p8inf = nil then exit; //No es la clave de llave privada correcta
  fLlave := EVP_PKCS82PKEY(p8inf);
    Result := true;
  finally
X509_SIG_free(p8);
BIO_free(bioDER);
EVP_cleanup;
  end;
end;
```

the. KEY and its private key are correct, it is the first thing I check in the debug.

the most strange is that I have 2 folders one where the application is in production and the other test. and only in the test folder not working properly.

the application should run under Citrix.

on the development computer everything works perfectly, the error is in the implementation and the test folder,

the Citrix server is Win Server 2003

Thanks in advance if anyone can help me find this error

Comment: As Citrix works sometimes by unknown rules, I suggest you to verify exactly the attributes of those folders and the application permissions for the process.

Answer (score 0):

I am from Mexico too and also I've developed an open source library for the digital invoicing (Facturacion Electronica) for Delphi, and had also fought with OpenSSL and the Delphi implementation of it.

Actually our code looks very similar, you can look at my "ClaseOpenSSL.pas" code in which I open the private key:

```
function TOpenSSL.AbrirLlavePrivada(Ruta, ClaveLlavePrivada : String) : pPKCS8_Priv_Key_Info;
var
    bioArchivoLlave : pBIO;
    sMsgErr: String;
    p8 : pX509_SIG;
    p8inf : pPKCS8_Priv_Key_Info;
    {$IF CompilerVersion >= 20}
        p8pass: PAnsiChar;
    {$ELSE}
        p8pass: PChar;
    {$IFEND}
begin
    // Creamos el objeto en memoria para leer la llave en formato binario .DER (.KEY)
    bioArchivoLlave := BIO_new(BIO_s_file());

    if Not FileExists(Ruta) then
      Raise ENoExisteArchivoException.Create('El archivo de llave privada no existe.');

    // Checamos que la extension de la llave privada sea la correcta
    if AnsiPos('.PEM', Uppercase(Ruta)) > 0 then
      Raise ELlaveFormatoIncorrectoException.Create('La llave privada debe de ser el archivo binario (.key, .cer) y ' +
            'no el formato base64 .pem');

    // Leemos el archivo de llave binario en el objeto creado en memoria
    // DIferentes parametros si usa Delphi 2009 o superior...
    {$IF CompilerVersion >= 20}
        if BIO_read_filename(bioArchivoLlave, PWideChar(AnsiString(Ruta))) = 0 then
    {$ELSE}
        if BIO_read_filename(bioArchivoLlave, PChar(AnsiString(Ruta))) = 0 then
    {$IFEND}
          raise ELlaveLecturaException.Create('Error al leer llave privada. Error reportado: '+
                ObtenerUltimoMensajeDeError);

    // Checamos que la clave no est� vacia
    if Trim(ClaveLlavePrivada) = '' then
      raise ELlavePrivadaClaveIncorrectaException.Create('La clave de la llave privada esta vacia');

    // Convertimos al tipo adecuado de acuerdo a la version de Delphi...
    {$IF CompilerVersion >= 20}
        // Delphi 2009 o superior
        p8pass:=PAnsiChar(AnsiString(ClaveLlavePrivada));
    {$ELSE}
        p8pass:=PChar(AnsiString(ClaveLlavePrivada));
    {$IFEND}

    p8:=nil;
    p8inf:=nil;

    try
        //  Leemos la llave en formato binario (PKCS8)
        p8 := d2i_PKCS8_bio(bioArchivoLlave, nil);
        if not Assigned(p8) then
          raise ELlaveLecturaException.Create('Error al leer llave privada. Error reportado: '+
                ObtenerUltimoMensajeDeError);

        // Des encriptamos la llave en memoria usando la clave proporcionada
        p8inf := PKCS8_decrypt(p8, p8pass, StrLen(p8pass));
        if Not Assigned(p8inf) then
        begin
           sMsgErr:=ObtenerUltimoMensajeDeError;
           // TODO: Crear excepciones para los diferentes tipos de error que puede haber al
           // tratar de desencriptar la llave privada
           // Llave incorrecta (Mensaje exacto: 23077074:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_pbe_crype:pkcs12 cipherfinal error)
           if ((AnsiPos('cipherfinal error', sMsgErr) > 0) or // clave incorrecta
              (AnsiPos('bad decrypt', sMsgErr) > 0))   // clave incorrecta
           then
              raise ELlavePrivadaClaveIncorrectaException.Create('La clave de la llave privada fue incorrecta')
           else
              if (AnsiPos('unknown pbe algorithm', sMsgErr) > 0) then // Clave vacia o pertenece a la FIEL
                Raise ELlavePareceSerFiel.Create('Al parecer la llave privada pertenece a la FIEL')
              else
                raise ELlaveLecturaException.Create('Error desconocido al desencriptar llave privada. Error reportado: '+
                      ObtenerUltimoMensajeDeError);
        end;
    finally
        // Liberamos las variables usadas en memoria
        X509_SIG_free(p8);
          BIO_free(bioArchivoLlave);
    end;

    Result:=p8inf;
end;
```

OpenSSL being a C library tends to be very very picky with parameters and passing the right data types and buffers, etc. also is very important that you free the allocated "pBIO" vars.

You are welcome to contribute to the library if you want, help is always welcome :)

The Github project is at:
http://github.com/bambucode/tfacturaelectronica

And our (pretty new) support group is at:
http://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tfacturaelectronica

Regards!